# How to display (or animate) three figures one by one for certain times, in Tikz/PGF?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, animations

In [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/695145/how-to-draw-3-equal-circles-inside-a-circle-in-tikz-or-other-way/695157?noredirect=1#comment1726117_695157), I have learned to plot the following three interesting figures in mathematics (p-adic numers):

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[ ] (0,0) circle [radius=3];
        \node at (0,2) {0};
        \node at (2,-1) {1};
        \node at (-2,-1) {2};
        \end{tikzpicture}
```

```
\newcommand{\RA}{1.5}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\RB}{\RA*(1+2/sqrt(3)}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[ ] (0,0) circle[radius=\RB cm];
        \foreach \ang in {90,210,330}
        \draw[ ] (\ang:\RB-\RA) circle[radius=\RA cm];
        \node[red] at (0,2.5) {0};
        \node[red] at (-0.8,1.5) {6};
        \node[red] at (0.8,1.5) {3};
        \node[red] at (1.7,-0.1) {1};
        \node[red] at (2.4,-1.3) {4};
        \node[blue] at (1,-1.3) {7};
        \node[red] (8) at (-2.4,-1.3) {8};
        \node[blue] at (-1,-1.3) {5};
        \node[red] at (-1.7,-0.1) {2};
        \end{tikzpicture}
```

```
\newcommand{\RRA}{4}
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\RRB}{\RRA/(1+2/sqrt(3)}
            \begin{tikzpicture}
            \draw[ ] (0,0) circle[radius=\RRA cm];
            \foreach \ang [count = \i from 1] in {90,210,330}
            \draw[ ] (\ang:\RRA-\RRB) coordinate (center-\i) circle[radius=\RRB cm];
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\RRC}{\RRB/(1+2/sqrt(3)}
            \foreach \i in {1,2,3}
            \foreach \ang in {90,210,330}
            \draw[ ] ($(center-\i)+(\ang:\RRB-\RRC)$) circle[radius=\RRC cm];
            \node[red] at (0,3.6) {0};
            \node[red] at (0.3,3) {18};
            \node[green] at (-0.3,3) {9};
            \node[red] at (0.9,2.1) {6};
            \node[red] at (1.2,1.4) {24};
            \node[green] at (0.5,1.4) {15};
            \node[cyan] at (-0.5,1.4) {21};
            \node[cyan] at (-0.9,2.1) {3};
            \node at (-1.2,1.4) {12};
            \node[red] at (1.8,0.5) {2};
            \node[purple] at (-1.8,0.5) {1};
            \node at (-2.2,-0.33) {10};
            \node[purple] at (-1.4,-0.33) {19};
            \node[red] at (2.2,-0.33) {20};
            \node[green] at (1.4,-0.33) {11};
            \node[red] at (2.7,-1) {8};
            \node[red] at (3.2,-1.8) {26};
            \node[green] at (2.3,-1.8) {17};
            \node[cyan] (7) at (1,-1.1) {5};
            \node[cyan] (7) at (1.5,-1.8) {23};
            \node (7) at (0.5,-1.8) {14};
            \node[red] at (-2.7,-1) {4};
            \node at (-3.2,-1.8) {13};
            \node[red] at (-2.3,-1.8) {22};
            \node[purple] (7) at (-1,-1.1) {7};
            \node (7) at (-1.5,-1.8) {16};
            \node[purple] (7) at (-0.5,-1.8) {25};
            \end{tikzpicture}
```

The above three Tikz codes gives the following three figures, respectively:

[image]

[image]

[image]

**My question:**

I want to animate these three figures in such a way that the first figure will be displayed for 5 seconds, then the second figures will be displayed for 5 seconds and then the same for third figure.

I got [PGF/TikZ manual](https://tikz.dev/tikz-animations#sec-26.2.1) but unable to apply here.

I appreciate your assitance.

**Edit:**

I have my preamble:

```
\documentclass[12pt,reqno]{amsart}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\pgfplotsset{ytick style={draw=none}}
\pgfplotsset{xtick style={draw=none}}
\topmargin=0.02cm
\textwidth =  17cm
\textheight = 23cm
\baselineskip=11pt
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0.01 pt}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{0.01 pt}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.4}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ }
%\usepackage[bookmarks=false]{hyperref}
%\usetikzlibrary{animations}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{accents}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{calligra}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\hypersetup{colorlinks, 
    breaklinks,
    linkcolor=red,
    citecolor=red,
    linktocpage=true}
\newtheorem{fig}{figure}[section]
\numberwithin{figure}{section}
\newcommand\norm[1]{\left\lVert#1\right\rVert}
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{lem}[thm]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{prop}[thm]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{cor}{Corollary}[thm]
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{defn}{Definition}[section]
\newtheorem{conj}{Conjecture}[section]
\newtheorem{exmp}{Example}[section]
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem*{rem}{Remark}
\newtheorem*{note}{Note}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\makeatletter
\@namedef{subjclassname@2020}{%
    \textup{2020} Mathematics Subject Classification}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
....
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your code is not compilable. Please turn it into a complete, compilable example.

Comment: @AlexG, which one is not compiling ? I can compile all 3 codes and I generated the figures in TeXstudio 2.12.6. Moreover, you can see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/695145/how-to-draw-3-equal-circles-inside-a-circle-in-tikz-or-other-way/695157?noredirect=1#comment1726117_695157). Have you added `\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}` in the preamble ?

Comment: None. Compilable code examples start with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}`. It is the questioners task to make the code complete. Please familiarise yourself with this site's conventions.

Comment: @AlexG, but all are alright in my TeXstudio 2.12.6 editor. Still not working, then you can suggest me with any three figures (say, circle, triangle, square) instead of my figures so that I can follow the trick

Comment: Animation mostly consists of having many pages with the same page number.

Comment: @JohnKormylo, can you give an example as answer ?

Comment: See beamer class.  Every `\pause` causes the page to be duplicated.  You might be able to do something with eforms and java script.

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/286280/textfield-and-animateinline

Comment: @JohnKormylo, I know the function of `\pause`. Thanks. However the link you mentioned doesn't deal with Tikz. I am seeking something with Tikz because I have drawn my figures with Tikz

Comment: @learner Please update your question to make your code fragments compilable. Do you use beamer or another class? You can use beamer overlays with tikz.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz, my code is compiling nicely. I am using TeXstudio editor. You can [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/695145/how-to-draw-3-equal-circles-inside-a-circle-in-tikz-or-other-way/695157?noredirect=1#comment1726117_695157), others answered it. See their codes.

Comment: You code is missing a documentclass, the necessary packages and a `document` environment. It does not compile as it is shown in your question.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz, ok, please see the edit, I have added my preamble

Comment: @learner Thanks. amsart means no playing with `\pause` :)

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz, I use \pause in beamer presentation.

Comment: ... but you use amsart here, so `\pause` is not available.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz, Is `\documentclass{article}` alright ?

Comment: `amsart` is fine. But your preamble is full of irrelevant pkgs. Please remove the unneeded ones. And insert your TikZ code in the body of the document. This may help you to set up a good example: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that

Comment: @AlexG, thanks. Indeed, I have used several package for seeral purposes in the last 3-4 years and which is why so many commands. But I didn't understand your comment "And insert your TikZ code in the body of the document". Which body ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the code in OP is not complete/compilable, a simple example follows to demonstrate how to set up an animation where each frame is shown for 5 seconds:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{animate}

\begin{document}
\begin{animateinline}[autoplay]{0.2}% 0.2 FPS corresponds to 5 s of frame visibility
  \fbox{1}
\newframe
  \fbox{2}
\newframe
  \fbox{3}
\newframe % <-- this makes the last one disappear after another 5 s, as requested
\end{animateinline}
\end{document}
```

The frame rate can be set individually for each frame or animation section by means of the optional `\newframe` argument:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{animate}

\begin{document}
\begin{animateinline}[autoplay]{0.2}% 0.2 FPS corresponds to 5 s of frame visibility
  \fbox{1}
\newframe[0.5] % the next frame is shown for 2 s
  \fbox{2}
\newframe[0.2] % reset to 5 s visibility
  \fbox{3}
\newframe % <-- this makes the last one disappear after another 5 s, as requested
\end{animateinline}
\end{document}
```

Okular and A-Reader can be used for viewing the animation.

Comment: Thanks. But my code compiling, otherwise how could I generate those figures ? Please [see here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/695145/how-to-draw-3-equal-circles-inside-a-circle-in-tikz-or-other-way/695157?noredirect=1#comment1726117_695157), I got the main code from it.

Comment: What would be in the `\fbox{1}`, `\fbox{2}`, `\fbox{3}` ? Can I subsitute my codes in place 1, 2 or 3 ?

Comment: Please see my preamble in the edited question, which can compile my code.

Comment: Can you please clarify the use of \fbox{1}, \fbox{2}, \fbox{3} ? In general, we enclose some text with this funtion. But I have to write Tikz-code to generate figures

Comment: `\fbox{...}` is for demonstration purposes only. Anything that produces visible content of non-zero width and height can be used instead.

Comment: Great! It is working. I put my TikZ codes into the `\fbox{}`s and the generated pdf showing animation. Now please tell me how to loop it or cycle it ? I mean I want to display the figure 1-->2-->3-->1-->2-->3....so on

Comment: Add the `loop` option for a repeating animation. `\fbox` is not required at all unless you want to have a frame drawn around your graphics.

Comment: For `loop`, we have to use the syntax `\foreach var_names in {values_for_each_var}{% sentences inside the loop};`. What are the variables here and what are their values in my case?

Comment: No additional code or variables. Just add `, loop` in the options argument of `animateinline`. And also remove `\fbox` from your code.

Comment: Do you mean `\begin{animateinline}[loop].....\end{animateinline}` ?

Comment: Yes, it is as simple.

Comment: Thank you so much. You solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

This uses the `texpower` package.  It is every bit as complicated as beamer, but totally different in application.

```
\documentclass[12pt,reqno]{amsart}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\pgfplotsset{ytick style={draw=none}}
\pgfplotsset{xtick style={draw=none}}
\topmargin=0.02cm
\textwidth =  17cm
\textheight = 23cm
\baselineskip=11pt
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0.01 pt}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{0.01 pt}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.4}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ }
%\usepackage[bookmarks=false]{hyperref}
%\usetikzlibrary{animations}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{accents}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{calligra}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\hypersetup{colorlinks, 
    breaklinks,
    linkcolor=red,
    citecolor=red,
    linktocpage=true}
\newtheorem{fig}{figure}[section]
\numberwithin{figure}{section}
\newcommand\norm[1]{\left\lVert#1\right\rVert}
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{lem}[thm]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{prop}[thm]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{cor}{Corollary}[thm]
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{defn}{Definition}[section]
\newtheorem{conj}{Conjecture}[section]
\newtheorem{exmp}{Example}[section]
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem*{rem}{Remark}
\newtheorem*{note}{Note}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\makeatletter
\@namedef{subjclassname@2020}{%
    \textup{2020} Mathematics Subject Classification}
\makeatother

\usepackage[display]{texpower}

\begin{document}
Some text.

\stepwise{%
\steponce{\begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[ ] (0,0) circle [radius=3];
        \node at (0,2) {0};
        \node at (2,-1) {1};
        \node at (-2,-1) {2};
        \end{tikzpicture}}
        
\steponce{\newcommand{\RA}{1.5}%
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\RB}{\RA*(1+2/sqrt(3)}%
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[ ] (0,0) circle[radius=\RB cm];
        \foreach \ang in {90,210,330}
        \draw[ ] (\ang:\RB-\RA) circle[radius=\RA cm];
        \node[red] at (0,2.5) {0};
        \node[red] at (-0.8,1.5) {6};
        \node[red] at (0.8,1.5) {3};
        \node[red] at (1.7,-0.1) {1};
        \node[red] at (2.4,-1.3) {4};
        \node[blue] at (1,-1.3) {7};
        \node[red] (8) at (-2.4,-1.3) {8};
        \node[blue] at (-1,-1.3) {5};
        \node[red] at (-1.7,-0.1) {2};
        \end{tikzpicture}}
        
\steponce{\newcommand{\RRA}{4}%
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\RRB}{\RRA/(1+2/sqrt(3)}%
            \begin{tikzpicture}
            \draw[ ] (0,0) circle[radius=\RRA cm];
            \foreach \ang [count = \i from 1] in {90,210,330}
            \draw[ ] (\ang:\RRA-\RRB) coordinate (center-\i) circle[radius=\RRB cm];
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\RRC}{\RRB/(1+2/sqrt(3)}
            \foreach \i in {1,2,3}
            \foreach \ang in {90,210,330}
            \draw[ ] ($(center-\i)+(\ang:\RRB-\RRC)$) circle[radius=\RRC cm];
            \node[red] at (0,3.6) {0};
            \node[red] at (0.3,3) {18};
            \node[green] at (-0.3,3) {9};
            \node[red] at (0.9,2.1) {6};
            \node[red] at (1.2,1.4) {24};
            \node[green] at (0.5,1.4) {15};
            \node[cyan] at (-0.5,1.4) {21};
            \node[cyan] at (-0.9,2.1) {3};
            \node at (-1.2,1.4) {12};
            \node[red] at (1.8,0.5) {2};
            \node[purple] at (-1.8,0.5) {1};
            \node at (-2.2,-0.33) {10};
            \node[purple] at (-1.4,-0.33) {19};
            \node[red] at (2.2,-0.33) {20};
            \node[green] at (1.4,-0.33) {11};
            \node[red] at (2.7,-1) {8};
            \node[red] at (3.2,-1.8) {26};
            \node[green] at (2.3,-1.8) {17};
            \node[cyan] (7) at (1,-1.1) {5};
            \node[cyan] (7) at (1.5,-1.8) {23};
            \node (7) at (0.5,-1.8) {14};
            \node[red] at (-2.7,-1) {4};
            \node at (-3.2,-1.8) {13};
            \node[red] at (-2.3,-1.8) {22};
            \node[purple] (7) at (-1,-1.1) {7};
            \node (7) at (-1.5,-1.8) {16};
            \node[purple] (7) at (-0.5,-1.8) {25};
            \end{tikzpicture}}}
            
Some more text
\end{document}
```

Comment: How to create a loop  or cycle? That means the animation will repeat

Comment: There is a `\movie` commmand, but every time I try to use it, it goes into an infinite loop.